FileSystemMoveEvent cannot be triggered?
I cannot find a way to trigger FileSystemMoveEvent.
Here is a simple code
final uri1 = Uri.file('junk.file');
final file1 = File.fromUri(uri1).absolute;
final sub = file1.watch().listen(print);

file1.create(); // triggers FileSystemCreateEvent

file1.writeAsString('A'); // triggers FileSystemModifyEvent

final parentUri = Directory.current.uri;
file1.renameSync('${parentUri.path}junk1.file'); // triggers FileSystemDeleteEvent
// or file1.delete(); // triggers FileSystemDeleteEvent

All events other than the move event can be triggered. I even tried renaming the parent directory, but no move event triggered.
So, What triggers FileSystemMoveEvent?
API Links:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.5.1/dart-io/FileSystemMoveEvent-class.html
https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.5.1/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/watch.html


In the example below, a FileSystemMoveEvent is triggered by moving a file in a directory. Tested using Dart SDK version: 3.5.0 (stable) on "linux_x64".
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  final uri = Uri.file('test.file');
  final file = File.fromUri(uri).absolute;
  final directory = Directory.current;

  final streamSubscription = directory.watch().listen(print);

  await file.create(); // triggers FileSystemCreateEvent
  // await file.writeAsString('A'); // triggers FileSystemModifyEvent

  final processResult = await Process.run(
    'mv',
    ['test.file', 'test_bak.file'],
    workingDirectory: directory.path,
  );
  
  await streamSubscription.cancel();

  print('Exiting: ${processResult.exitCode}');
}


Console output:
$ dart main.dart 
FileSystemCreateEvent('/home/dan/stackoverflow/example/test.file',
  isDirectory=false)
FileSystemMoveEvent('/home/dan/stackoverflow/example/test.file',
  isDirectory=false, 
  destination=/home/dan/stackoverflow/example/test_bak.file)
Exiting: 0


Not working in my system (macos). The console returns only Exiting: 0. I tried to wrap streamSubscription.cancel() in Future.delayed, then console printedExiting: 0 FileSystemCreateEvent('/Users/test.file', isDirectory=false) FileSystemDeleteEvent('/Users/test.file') FileSystemCreateEvent('/Users/test_bak.file', isDirectory=false) FileSystemCreateEvent('/Users/test_bak.file', isDirectory=false)

Added info about my system and Dart version. Without the line await streamSubscription.cancel(); the program does not terminate and keeps listening to the stream.

That behavior is true for my environment as well since the received stream is broadcast. I have to wrap the streamSubscription.cancel(); in Future.delayed to get create and delete events. Nonetheless, I cannot find a way to trigger move event.
